# Does Apple run a search engine?

Tags: search-engine

Apache logs for my [genealogy website](https://UniGen.us) show fetches in a single day from many different IP addresses that are subdomains of applebot.apple.com.

Does Apple have a search engine?

Comment: Yes: https://www.webservicesct.com/blog/applebot-web-crawler/
(Put here because SE won't allow it as an answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple does not have a web site where you can go to search the web in the style of Google, Bing and others.

Apple however does have a web crawler ([Applebot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204683)) that fetches publicly available web pages for indexing, similar to Google, Bing and others. The index is used for providing search results to those using for example Siri to search the web via voice, or for those using Spotlight Search directly on the desktop in macOS.